# c# WebAPI Owin jwt RefreshToken invalid_grant

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt

I am stumped by this behavior.  Basically, when a refresh of a token is requested, WebAPI goes through the logic of removing the old refresh_token from the data, and I don't see any errors in the debugger.  However, the API returns a HTTP 400 with "invalid_grant" as the error.

Startup.cs

```
// OAuth Server configuration
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = false,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    AccessTokenFormat = new AccessTokenJwtFormat(issuer),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
    RefreshTokenFormat = new RefreshTokenJwtFormat(issuer),
    Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider()
};

// OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

SimpleRefreshTokenProvider.cs

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{

    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
        {
            return;
        }

        var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
        var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime");

        var _repo = ClientDbProvider.GetInstance();
        var token = new RefreshToken()
        {
            Id = ClientHelper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
            ClientId = clientid,
            Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime))
        };

        context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = new DateTimeOffset(token.IssuedUtc);
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(token.ExpiresUtc);
        context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("refreshTokenId", refreshTokenId);
        context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "refreshToken"));
        token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
        var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);
        if (result)
        {
            context.SetToken(token.ProtectedTicket);
        }

        return;
    }

    public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {

        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        var _repo = ClientDbProvider.GetInstance();
        string hashedTokenId = ClientHelper.GetHash(context.Token);
        var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

        if (refreshToken != null)
        {
            //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
            context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
            var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
        }
    }

    public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

RefreshTokenJwtFormat.cs

```
public class RefreshTokenJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private const string AudiencePropertyKey = "audience";

        private readonly string _issuer = string.Empty;

        public RefreshTokenJwtFormat(string issuer)
        {
            _issuer = issuer;
            audStore = new AudiencesStore();
        }

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            string audienceId = data.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey(AudiencePropertyKey) ? data.Properties.Dictionary[AudiencePropertyKey] : null;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(audienceId)) throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthenticationTicket.Properties does not include audience");

            var audience = GetAudience(audienceId);
            string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = audience.Base64Secret;

            var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature,
                    SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);

            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
            var payload = new JwtPayload(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime);
            if (data.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey("refreshTokenId"))
            {
                payload.Add("refreshTokenId", data.Properties.Dictionary["refreshTokenId"]);
            }

            var header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken securityToken = handler.ReadToken(protectedText);
            var audienceId = ((JwtSecurityToken)securityToken).Claims.First(x => x.Type == "aud").Value;
            var audience = GetAudience(audienceId);

            string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = audience.Base64Secret;
            var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
            var securityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = audienceId,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = _issuer
            };

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
            try
            {
                principal = handler.ValidateToken(protectedText, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new AuthenticationTicket(principal.Identities.First(), new AuthenticationProperties());
        }

        private Models.Audience GetAudience(string audienceId)
        {
            var findAudTask = Task.Run(() => audStore.FindAudienceAsync(audienceId));
            findAudTask.Wait();
            var audience = findAudTask.Result;
            return audience;
        }

        private AudiencesStore audStore;
    }
```

Comment: have you found any solution? same here

Answer (score 3):

First you need
implement GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context) in your CustomOAuthProvider
something like

```
public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
        {

            // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
            var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
            //newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

            var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
            context.Validated(newTicket);

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

Second you need to change your method Unprotect in RefreshTokenJwtFormat.

replace

```
return new AuthenticationTicket(principal.Identities.First(), new AuthenticationProperties());
```

with

```
return new AuthenticationTicket(principal.Identities.First(), new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IssuedUtc = validatedToken.ValidFrom,
                    ExpiresUtc = validatedToken.ValidTo
                });
```

Comment: This second section for the timestamps solved my issue. Makes perfect sense, but like finding a needle in a haystack with so many tiny pieces and parts to stitch together

Answer (score 1):

i have similar (working) code. I'm not a specialist on this but i compared my code a bit and noticed:

in SimpleRefreshToken.cs:

in receiveAsync, my code ends with:

```
context.SetTicket(context.Ticket);   
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
```

Which sets the ticket and return a value.

The same for createAsync, my code ends with:

```
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
```

Allthough, no idea if this will help